# @OrderColumn in Hibernate/JPA results in redundant UPDATE SQL statement

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a simple bi-directional parent/child relationship where the children are in an ordered list.

The parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent")
public class Parent {
    @Id
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderColumn(name = "childIndex")
    private final List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addChild(final Child child) {
        this.children.add(child);
    }
}
```

The child:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Child")
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "hibernate-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "hibernate-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentName")
    private Parent parent;

    Child() {}

    public Child(final Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

I add an instance of the `Parent` and `Child` like so:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = ...
try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
    session.beginTransaction();

    Parent parent = new Parent();
    parent.setName("SomeName");
    Child child = new Child(parent);
    parent.addChild(child);

    session.merge(parent);

    session.getTransaction()
            .commit();
}
```

This works fine and results in the following SQL:

```
Hibernate: select parent0_.name as name1_1_1_, children1_.parentName as parentNa2_0_3_, children1_.id as id1_0_3_, children1_.itemIndex as itemInde3_3_, children1_.id as id1_0_0_, children1_.parentName as parentNa2_0_0_ from Parent parent0_ left outer join Child children1_ on parent0_.name=children1_.parentName where parent0_.name=?
Hibernate: insert into Parent (name) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into Child (parentName, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: update Child set itemIndex=? where id=?
```

Is it possible to remove the `UPDATE` statement and instead set the `childIndex` when the `Child` row is inserted?

I tried setting `nullable=false` on the `OrderColumn` annotation, but that resulted in a `null value in column "childindex" violates not-null constraint` error, as Hibernate still tries to insert the `Child` column without setting the `childindex`.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Per Mick's suggestion, I explicitly added a `childIndex` attribute to the Child entity, like so:

```
@Column(nullable = false)
private int childIndex;
```

While this does result in the column becoming non-null, it does not remove the extra `UPDATE` statement. With this change, Hibernate appears to set the `childIndex` to 0 on INSERT (no matter what index the child actually is; I've tested this by adding more children), and then performs an UPDATE to correct the index. I'm assuming Hibernate is just using whatever value happens to be on the Child object, which is 0 by default, and then updating it after the INSERT is complete, even if it happens to be the correct value.

Comment: The Child-Entity still needs childIndex to be defined, right? JPA does not know about this column yet, although it uses it for ordering.

Comment: @Mick As it is right now, JPA appears to create the childIndex column, even though I did not explicitly define it on the Child entity. My concern is that JPA does not set the value for this column in the initial INSERT statement for the Child entity, but instead sets it in a separate UPDATE statement.

Explicitly adding a childIndex column to the Child entity results in the value being set to 0 upon the initial INSERT (no matter what the actual index should be), then being updated to the correct value.

Comment: Hello, did you finally found a solution about this ?

Answer (score 0):

ok, sounds like Hibernate is doing quite a bit of magic here when you merge the parent entity. It seems to infer that there must be an additional attribute on the child entity - but this fact is being discovered lazy - hence your double UPDATE. What about if you also explicitly defined a proper "childIndex" attribute on the child entity? That @Column annotation would be the right place to annotate your nullable-requirements. Also that should force Hibernate to insert the value right away with the first UPDATE statement.